# Configure Visual Studio Project to put generated classes into source directory

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, configuration, cmake, code-generation

We are using `cmake` to configure our project and make the configuration process for every team member as simple as it could be.
The project itself is completely windows oriented and a mix of `ATL`and `MFC`.
Now in the cmake-ification process of the project we notified some difficulties when using class wizard in visual studio. Every time a class for a control is generated the class is placed within the build directory (the directory, where cmake puts the solutions (`.sln`) and `.vcxproj` files in).

```
---+project-root-dir
   +---build
   |   \---<project>     #where the .vcxproj and generated sources are put somehow
   \---<project>         #repo - where the sources are organized usually
```

Is there a way to configure `cmake` to make visual studio know where to put the (generated) source files?
This is nothing else but a path configuration issue for visual studio I guess.
FYI: I'm using VS13, programming language is (visual) c++